# Role specific login in Laravel 4

Tags: authentication, laravel, laravel-4, role

I am logging in the system successfully but
 I want that the user whose role is 'Administrator' can only go to all the routes and user having role as 'Manager' can go to 'Home' and 'GetDocumentDetails' else the other login users will be restricted to home page and the guest to Login page.
My route and filter files are as follows:

---

Routes:

```
Route::post('/login', function()
{
    $user = array(
    'username' => Input::get('username'),
    'password' => Input::get('password'));
    // verify user credentials  
    if (Auth::attempt($user,true))
    {   
        $role= Auth::user()->userrole;
        return Redirect::route('home');
    }
}
// Route for getting document details using get method
Route::get('GetDocumentDetailsById',array('as'=>'GetDocumentDetailsById','uses'=>'DocumentController@GetDocumentDetailsById'));

// Route for guest user 
Route::filter('guest', function()
{
    if (Auth::check()) 
    return Redirect::route('home')->with('flash_notice', 'You are already logged in!');
    // Redirect Log-in user to his home page
});
```

---

Filters:

```
/* Filter to redirect guest user to login page */
Route::filter('auth', function()
{
    $role=Auth::user();
    if (Auth::guest()) return Redirect::guest('login');
});


Route::filter('auth.basic', function()
{
    return Auth::basic('username');
});

Route::filter('guest', function()
{
    if (Auth::check()) return Redirect::to('/');
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend using Zizaco's [Entrust](https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust) and [Confide](https://github.com/Zizaco/confide) packages for this purpose, as they greatly simplify this task.

Follow the tutorials on these pages after installing both packages, and then you can limit access to certain routes just by defining Route Permission filters or regular Route filters. No need for any additional logic in controller actions.

These Route Permission filters can easily be defined like this:

```
// Any route under admin is only accessible by users with role Admin.
// Redirect happens if user doesn't have this role.

Entrust::routeNeedsRole('admin*', 'Admin', Redirect::to('/'));
```

A Route filter based on permissions would look like this:

```
Route::filter('myFilter', function()
{
    if (!Entrust::can('get_document_details') )
    {
        return Redirect::to('/');
    }
});
```

This filter could then be applied to any route. See the Entrust documentation for more examples and features. Entrust is really versatile.

Comment: In the given link its written


Run the Composer update command
$ composer update


how and where I run it??
In command prompt I have written this but its showing 'not recognised program'

Comment: If you have installed Laravel 4, you will probably have done so via Composer. Go to your Laravel root folder (the one that contains a file called `composer.json`) and run the command "php path/to/composer.phar update".

Comment: When I am writing on command prompt 
php artisan entrust:migration

Then, the error is coming
'Zizaco\Entrust\EntrustFacade' file is not found.
I have added the line in providers and alias array of config/app.php

Comment: Try `php /path/to/composer.phar dump-autoload`. This will make Laravel "see" the newly installed classes.

Comment: I have dump-autoloaded Sir but still the same error.
I want to ask that after including the file name in 'require' of composer.json then the files will be automatically downloaded or I need to download it manually.

Comment: `composer update` installs the files automatically. You then need to add the proper lines to the `aliases` and `providers` array in `app/config/app.php`. Please read up on how to use Composer with Laravel.

Comment: When I run Command : 

 
php composer.json update
It executes perfectly and I can see the files entrust and conflict in require of composer.json.
In app file I have written 
'Zizaco\Entrust\EntrustServiceProvider'
in last line of provider and
  'Entrust'        => 'Zizaco\Entrust\EntrustFacade'

in last line of alias.

Comment: Problem in 
public function createProvider(Application $app, $provider)
 {
  return new $provider($app);
 }

 in file C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation